# how i can change element Style height

Tags: css, smartgwt

I cannot change the height at this element. I have tried to change that by code, but it didn't work. It's like a default style applied. Does anyone have an idea how to change that default?

```
uploadItem = new UploadItem("image");
uploadItem.setTitle(caption );
uploadItem.setWrapTitle(false);
uploadForm.setHeight(500);`
```

here is the [firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDyGj.jpg)

Comment: Which element the UploadItem or the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar like

```
$('#myimage').width(700); // Units are assumed to be pixels
$('#myimage').height(700);
```

Where myimage is your div.

Comment: i need to change it at run time in smartGWT .. not J query!
thanks,,

Comment: I cannot entirely recognise this `$()`-syntax from any CSS I know off? Is it some undocumented CSS3 feature? :)